# need to repeat Flask form, multiple instances of one form class

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi, flask-wtforms

NOTE: I know I can repeat the code for the form 10 times to do what I'm wanting to do. I'm trying to not repeat the code and reuse it 10 times, as all 10 forms are identical.

I'm building an automation timer with a flask backend to run on a raspberry pi, I'm doing this to be able to access the pi like a server and control the pi. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, I'm looping the same code and dynamically changing the info for each of 10 irrigation timers. 
So it's one html page with valve 1 and all it's settings THEN valve2....valve3...etc. Example of the html is at the bottom.

Having a constructor and trying to make multiple forms does not work, when I do this it keeps saying

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'webApp.forms.ValveForm object' has no     attribute 'valveName
```

This is example of what doesn't work for me

```
class ValveForm(FlaskForm):
def __init__(self, name):
    valveName = StringField("Name", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=100)], default = name)
    valveNotes = TextAreaField("Notes", validators=[Length(max=300)])
    valveOnOff = SelectField("on/off", choices=[("True", "on"), ("False", "off")])
    valveCycleIrrigate = SelectField("cycle or irrigate", choices=[("cycle", "Cycle"), ("irrigate", "Irrigate")])

    valveIrrigationTime = TimeField("valveIrrigationTime")
    valveTimeHour = StringField("valveTimeHour")
    valveTimeMinute = StringField("valveTimeMinute")
    #valveTimeSecond = StringField("valveTimeSecond")

    cycleOnTimeHour = StringField("cycleOnTimeHour")
    cycleOnTimeMinute = StringField("cycleOnTimeMinute")
    cycleOnTimeSeconds = StringField("cycleOnTimeSecond")

    cycleOffTimeHour = StringField("cycleOffTimeHour")
    cycleOffTimeMinute = StringField("cycleOffTimeMinute")
    cycleOffTimeSeconds = StringField("cycleOffTimeSecond")

    blackoutStart = TimeField("blackoutStart")
    blackoutStop = TimeField("blackoutStop")

    selectAll = BooleanField("Select All")
    monday = BooleanField("monday")
    tuesday = BooleanField("tuesday")
    wednesday = BooleanField("wednesday")
    thursday = BooleanField("thursday")
    friday = BooleanField("friday")
    saturday = BooleanField("saturday")
    sunday = BooleanField("sunday")

    daysTuple = (selectAll, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday)
```

it's working like below but of course this doesn't work. Because all 10 valves get the same information. I'm trying to individualize the info for each one. I need to do it in the class because I need to insert default values for previous settings. Normally people don't use forms like this so it's giving me problems.

```
class ValveForm(FlaskForm):
    valveName = StringField("Name", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=100)], default = "something")
    valveNotes = TextAreaField("Notes", validators=[Length(max=300)])
    valveOnOff = SelectField("on/off", choices=[("True", "on"), ("False", "off")])
    valveCycleIrrigate = SelectField("cycle or irrigate", choices=[("cycle", "Cycle"), ("irrigate", "Irrigate")])

    valveIrrigationTime = TimeField("valveIrrigationTime")
    valveTimeHour = StringField("valveTimeHour")
    valveTimeMinute = StringField("valveTimeMinute")
    #valveTimeSecond = StringField("valveTimeSecond")

    cycleOnTimeHour = StringField("cycleOnTimeHour")
    cycleOnTimeMinute = StringField("cycleOnTimeMinute")
    cycleOnTimeSeconds = StringField("cycleOnTimeSecond")

    cycleOffTimeHour = StringField("cycleOffTimeHour")
    cycleOffTimeMinute = StringField("cycleOffTimeMinute")
    cycleOffTimeSeconds = StringField("cycleOffTimeSecond")

    blackoutStart = TimeField("blackoutStart")
    blackoutStop = TimeField("blackoutStop")

    selectAll = BooleanField("Select All")
    monday = BooleanField("monday")
    tuesday = BooleanField("tuesday")
    wednesday = BooleanField("wednesday")
    thursday = BooleanField("thursday")
    friday = BooleanField("friday")
    saturday = BooleanField("saturday")
    sunday = BooleanField("sunday")

    daysTuple = (selectAll, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday)
```

And here's html for the valves which loops

```
{%extends "layout.html"%}

{%block body_content%}
{% for i in range(10) %}
    <h1>{{IrrigationValve.valveList[i].name}}</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {#{{ form.hidden_tag() }}#}
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ formList[i].valveName.label(class="form-control-label") }} </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        {% if formList[i].valveName.errors %}
                            {{ formList[i].valveName(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in valve.valveName.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ formList[i].valveName(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Notes</td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {{ formList[i].valveNotes(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>current state</td>
                <td>{{IrrigationValve.valveList[i].currentStateOn | trueFalseIndicator()}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>on/off</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ formList[i].valveOnOff(class="form-control form-control-lg", value=IrrigationValve.valveList[i].currentStateOn) }}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>testing</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" name="action" class="btn btn-danger" value="test">TEST</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cycle or irrigate</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ formList[i].valveCycleIrrigate(class="form-control form-control-lg", value=IrrigationValve.valveList[i].cycleOrIrrigate) }}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>irrigation times</td>
                <td>
                    {% if not IrrigationValve.valveList[i].irrigationTimes %}
                        None 
                    {% else %}
                        {% for key, value in IrrigationValve.valveList[i].irrigationTimes.items() %} 
                            time: {{ key | strf_time_converter() }}  duration: {{ value | deltaToHrMinSec() }}
                            <button type="submit" name="action" id="{{ key }}" value="irrigation-time-delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        {% endfor %} 
                    {% endif %}
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ formList[i].valveIrrigationTime() }}
                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="irrigation-time-add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cycle on time</td>
                <td>
                    {%if not IrrigationValve.valveList[i].cycleOnTime%}
                        None<br><br>
                        <div>
                            <label>Hours</label>
                            {{ formList[i].cycleOnTimeHour() }} <br>
                            <label>Minutes</label>
                            {{ formList[i].cycleOnTimeMinute }} <br>
                            <label>Seconds</label>
                            {{ formList[i].cycleOnTimeSeconds }} <br>
                            <button type="submit" name="action" value="cycle-on-time-add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    {%else%}
                        {{IrrigationValve.valveList[i].cycleOnTime | HrMinSec()}}
                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="cycle-on-time-delete" class="btn btn-primary">delete</button>
                    {%endif%}
                    <br><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cycle off time</td>
                <td>
                    {%if not IrrigationValve.valveList[i].cycleOffTime%}
                        None<br><br>
                        <form>
                            <div>
                                <label>Hours</label>
                                {{ formList[i].cycleOffTimeHour }}<br>
                                <label>Minutes</label>
                                {{ formList[i].cycleOffTimeMinute }}<br>
                                <label>Seconds</label>
                                {{ formList[i].cycleOffTimeSeconds }}<br>
                                <button type="button" name="action" value="cycle-off-time-add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    {%else%}
                        {{IrrigationValve.valveList[i].cycleOffTime | HrMinSec()}}
                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="cycle-off-time-delete" class="btn btn-primary">delete</button>
                    {%endif%}
                    <br><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>blackout start</td>
                <td>
                    {%if not IrrigationValve.valveList[i].blackoutStart%}
                        None
                        <br><br>
                        {{ formList[i].blackoutStart }}
                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="blackout-start-add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                    {%else%}
                        {{IrrigationValve.valveList[i].blackoutStart | strftimeConverter()}}
                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="blackout-start-delete" class="btn btn-primary">delete</button>
                    {%endif%}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>blackout stop</td>
                <td>
                    {%if not IrrigationValve.valveList[i].blackoutStop%}
                        None
                        <br><br>
                        {{ formList[i].blackoutStop }}
                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="blackout-stop-add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                    {%else%}
                        {{IrrigationValve.valveList[i].blackoutStop | strftimeConverter()}}
                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="blackout-stop-delete" class="btn btn-primary">delete</button>
                    {%endif%}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>days</td>
                <td>
                    {{ formList[i].selectAll }}{{ formList[i].selectAll.label }}<br>
                    <br>
                    {{ formList[i].monday }}{{ formList[i].monday.label }}<br>
                    {{ formList[i].tuesday }}{{ formList[i].tuesday.label }}<br>
                    {{ formList[i].wednesday }}{{ formList[i].wednesday.label }}<br>
                    {{ formList[i].thursday }}{{ formList[i].thursday.label }}<br>
                    {{ formList[i].friday }}{{ formList[i].friday.label }}<br>
                    {{ formList[i].saturday }}{{ formList[i].saturday.label }}<br>
                    {{ formList[i].sunday }}{{ formList[i].sunday.label }}<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
           <input class="btn-success btn-block btn-lg" type="submit" name="action" value="submit">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
{%endblock%}
```

and here is part of the app.py

```
@app.route("/valves", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def irrigationValve():
formList = [ValveForm(IrrigationValve.valveList[i].name) for i in range(10)]
for i in range(10):
    if formList[i].validate_on_submit():
        formList[i].setValve(irrigationValve.valveList[i])
        flash("changes saved", "success")
return render_template("valves.html", IrrigationValve=IrrigationValve, formList=formList)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another example of dynamic wtforms, for which there are numerous example questions on SO.

The wtforms class constructor requires attributes at the class level and not the instance level, so this works:

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    attribute = StringField()
    attribute2 = StringField()
```

while this does not work:

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    attribute2 = StringField()
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.attribute = StringField(arg)
```

The solution is to build a dynamic class constructor such as the following:

```
def Form(arg):
    class TempForm(FlaskForm):
        attribute2 = StringField()
    setattr(TempForm, 'attribute', StringField(arg))
    return TempForm()
```

This function accepts an argument, then dynamically constructs the class object in the appropriate format and returns an instance of it, and is used in the same way in your route:

```
form = Form(arg)
```

**edit for question**

and then you create your form list with:

```
arg_list = ['one', 'two', ..., 'ten']
form_list = [Form(arg=arg_list[i]) for i in range(10)]
```

There is only one form - no part of this answer suggested coding 10 separate forms.

Comment: So I have to repeat the same form class 10 times to make it work 10 different times? I know I can do that but I was hoping keep from repeating the code